# WP_Query calls all posts?

Tags: wp-query

I have this code that picks a random testimonial post.

```
    <?php
        $quote_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category' => 'quote',
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        );

        $quote  = new WP_Query($quote_args);

        if($quote->have_posts()):
            while($quote->have_posts()):
                $quote->the_post();
    ?>

    <p id="quote">
        <?php the_content_rss(); ?>
        <span><?php echo the_title(); ?></span>
    </p>

        <?php
            endwhile;
            endif;

            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

The testimonials are posts with a category of 'quote', the title of the post is the name of the person.

I have other posts in the site that have other categories but only the testimonial posts have a category of 'quote'.

The code works but I'm getting a random post picked from all the posts and not just the post's with a quote category.

Can anyone see a reason why I getting this, or any other reason this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such parameter as `category` for `WP_Query`, so WP is ignoring it. You should use `category_name`, where the value is the slug of the category.